# Inno setup quotes problem

Tags: windows, inno-setup, quotes

In my inno setup installer in [Run] section I want to run a cmd command, but here is the problem. I want to run an exe with parameters, 
"My Program.exe" install
I want to run like this but since it has spaces in the name I cannot run it without "" and this is gives me error because inno setup has "" too.
Similarly I want to start my service
net start "My Service"
and got same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try with something like this :

```
Run: " ""My Program.exe"" ";
```

The double quotes seems to be a quite good solution according to the [Inno Setup documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_params.htm)

Comment: Yes, I ran this and did not work.
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: " ""C:\My program.exe"" install"

Comment: Doubling the double quotes is the correct way to do it. If it's not working, then the app it's being passed to is not parsing it correctly.

Comment: Double quotes did not work for me either for defining windows service

Comment: @abbassebastian The `cmd.exe` needs `/C` parameter before the command: `Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/C ""C:\My program.exe"" install"`

Comment: @CédricJulien The `My%20program.exe` is wrong. Please delete this comment, not to confuse others.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are searching for:

> Run another Setup after install:
> [Run]
> Filename: "{#path}\My Setup.exe"; Parameters: "Parameter here"
>
> Run CMD with Parameter after install:
> [Run]
> Filename: "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe"; Parameters:"Parameter here"

etc.